# Can not access manually mounted hard drive from command line

Tags: permissions, mount, automounting

I am trying to manually install a USB hard drive from the command line on my Raspberry Pi. I am following the usual steps: Create a directory in /media, mount the drive,... However I can not access the drive as a regular user and since the root account is disabled...

```
pi@raspi:/media/pi $ ls -hal
total 113K
drwxr-x---+ 5 root root 4.0K Oct  1 22:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Oct  1 21:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 pi   pi    32K Jan  1  1970 342F-8BF2
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 1.0K Sep  1 11:29 SETTINGS
drwx------  1 root root  72K Sep 24 23:18 toshiba
```

`342F-8BF2` is a pendrive automatically mounted when starting the desktop environmnent, meanwhile `toshiba` is the directory that I have created with `mkdir` and where the HD is mounted.

How can the desktop create a directory as user `pi` with all the permissions that allow me to access/modify the pen drive but I can't?

EDIT:

In order to mount the HD I am using the following command

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/pi/toshiba
```

and these are the permissions for the `/media/pi` directory

```
pi@raspi:/media $ ls -hal
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4.0K Oct  1 21:41 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root 4.0K Jun 27 03:09 ..
drwxr-x---+  2 root root 4.0K Sep 22 00:32 peter
drwxr-x---+  5 root root 4.0K Oct  1 22:57 pi
```

Comment: Please post the command you are using to mount that drive.  If you have `sudo` access, you may be able to use that to fix the ownership/permissions of the mount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the filesystem type on the disk you’re mounting manually?

Filesystems that have no real support for Unix-style file ownership will usually need mount options to determine who can access them. If you specify no options, the default is to allow root access only.

Use the `id` command to identify the UID and GID numbers of your user account. I believe the `pi` user on a RasPi is usually UID 1000, GID 1000, so this might work for you:

```
sudo mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sdb1 /media/pi/toshiba
```

The desktop will most likely use `udisks2` or similar D-Bus service to actually handle the mounting; see `man udisksctl` to see how you can use the same service from the command line. It will automatically apply some mount options to assign the permissions for you if applicable.

If the disk/partition has a filesystem that can persistently store Unix-style file ownerships and permissions, then you can use the `chown` and `chmod` commands as an one-time action to set the permissions for the root directory of the filesystem:

```
<mount the filesystem>
sudo chown pi:pi /media/pi/toshiba
```

Note that changing the permissions of the /media/pi/toshiba directory while the filesystem is unmounted will have no effect on the permissions of the root directory of the filesystem on /dev/sdb1. They are two separate entities, although one covers the other when the filesystem is mounted.

Answer (score 1):

root is not disabled, only the ability to *login* as root is.  As you've discovered,  executing sudo without specifying a user will run the command as root.  One way to deal with the permission problem is to 'sudo chmod o+rx /media/pi' (and if you want to be able to write to the volume, replace the o+rx to o+rwx)  This is not a secure way to do things, but is the quickest and will be fine if you are the only user of the system.